# Squares instead of letters at BusyBox

Tags: boot, busybox

Instead of booting, the computer hoes to BusyBox, I can only type capital letters in BusyBox. Small letters come out as squares. I cannot send any commands.

[image]

Comment: IDK, but try (in lowercase), `^C^Cstty sane`.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written doesn't appear to relate in any way to the Ubuntu OS. [Please review the topics covered on this site over in the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).